# CSS Positions and floats everything is overlaying

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-float

Hi I have a problem with my css for some reason I can't get a div under another div so here is my code

Live demo adamlisik.co.uk/kantor2
This is my css

```
body{
margin: 0;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 18px;
padding:0px;
background-image:url('../images/bg-body.jpg');
background-attachment:fixed;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit;
  }
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 36px;
}
h3 {
  line-height: 27px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
h4,
    h5,
h6 {
  line-height: 18px;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
h5 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #999999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 9px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
    color:#0d0d0d;
}
hr{ border:none; height:1px; margin:30px 0; background-color:#CCCCCC; color:#CCCCCC; }
    .hr{ border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC; margin:30px 0; }
.container {
width:1000px;
margin: auto;
padding:0px;
background:#FFF;
}
.header { 
position:relative; 
z-index:10; 
background-image:url('../images/logo1.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left bottom; 
height:100px;
width:950px;
margin:auto;

}

ul#dropdown-menu{  float:right; list-style:none; margin-bottom:0px; padding-top:70px; }       
ul#dropdown-menu li{ float: left; }
ul#dropdown-menu li a{ display: block; padding:7px 21px 5px 0; font-size:16px; text-transform:none; color:#252525;text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; }            
ul#dropdown-menu li a:hover{ color:#FF0000;}
ul#dropdown-menu li.hover a{ text-decoration:underline;  }           
ul#dropdown-menu li.current > a{ color: #FF0000; }                             
ul#dropdown-menu li .sub-menu li a{ color:#252525; }                               
ul#dropdown-menu li.last > a{ padding-right:0px; }

.money {
    margin-top:20px;
    background-image:url('../images/hr-bg.jpg');
    height:120px
}

.content {
padding:25px 50px 10px;
}

.footer {
padding:5px 15px 10px;
}
```

Now as soon as you add the next two classes in css to make the tables go to ether side

```
 .left {
float:left;
}
.right {
float:right;}
```

Every thing changes the hr is above tables and all the footer styles don't work

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post your HTML? It would greatly help in understanding your problem.

Comment: How about just floating the first table left and leaving the second table alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the `float` property to an element it's removed from the normal flow, so its parent, which is still in the normal flow, behaves as if the floated element isn't its child anymore.

You can solve like this:

```css
.hr{ clear: both; }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because both children elements of `.content` are floated, thus the height of this  container behaves as it is contains only the first two `<p>` (non-floated) elements (As you can see the `hr` element is sitting just below you last paragraph).

To restore a correct height just apply some kind of non-strucutural clearing to the parent, like [easyclearing](http://dtott.com/thoughts/2007/12/10/clear-your-floats-the-right-way). Or just add

```
.content {
  height: auto; overflow: hidden 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the div below right before the class="hr" div

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

so it should look something like this

```
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="hr"></div>
<div class="footer">
```

That while cause the footer to be below the tables again.

Comment: I think that add empty markup only for clearing purposes is something to really avoid.